# how to make outline/border that disrespect border-radius property

Tags: html, css

I can hover any element on the page and there should be a selection with css property (for example additional css rule border). There can already be rules like position, border, outline for hovered element. If element has border-radius there is no way to make my border with rectangle shape. There are workaround like pseudo-element ::after but If I hover element that already have position (revert, static) I can't guarantee that this will work. It seems there should be another approach like creating extra tag (span or div) on hover element, but I have question. would it break my webpage (would it cause any small padding, margin that will change existing overlay of my page). Is it possible to do.

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

button::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -99;
  inset: 0px;  
  content: '';
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`border-image` doesn't respect `border-radius` so you can use it

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  outline: 2px solid red; /* instead of border */
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-image: 
    linear-gradient(black 0 0) 1
    /2px  /* control the width */
    /3px  /* control the offset */
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```